# Angular.js Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token :

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angurlar.js to call my Web API and I am getting error as:

```
P01:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : and in resources tab it is being shown that these braces should not be there {"ProductID1":"P01","ProductName1":"Pen","Quantity1":10,"Price1":12.0} kindly help me
```

this is my angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('StoreController', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {

        $scope.display = function () {

            //  $http.get('http://localhost:17279/api/Product/GetProduct/' + $scope.pid).success(function (data) {
            $http({
                method: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://localhost:17279/api/Product/GetProduct/' + $scope.pid,
                params: {
                    format: 'jsonp',
                    json_callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                }
            }).success(function (data) {
                {{data}}
            });
        }
    }]);
```

below code is in my WebAPI controller

```
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>{
            new       Product{ProductID1="P01",ProductName1="Pen",Quantity1=10,Price1=12},
             new Product{ProductID1="P02",ProductName1="Copy",Quantity1=12,Price1=20},
             new Product{ProductID1="P03",ProductName1="Pencil",Quantity1=15,Price1=22},
             new Product{ProductID1="P04",ProductName1="Eraser",Quantity1=20,Price1=27},
        };
    public List<Product> GetProductList()
    {
        return productList;
    }
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(string id)
    {
        var product = productList.FirstOrDefault(
            (p) => p.ProductID1 == id);
        if(product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
```

Apart from this I have a product model class in WebAPI which has 4 members and their properties namely : price,quantity,productID,productname

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the code that you are having problems with?

Comment: double curly braces should only be used in your html.

Comment: i tried console.log but then i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `{{data}}` in your `success` callback. This is angular's way of binding expressions to view and should not be used within your javascript code

```
$scope.display = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://localhost:17279/api/Product/GetProduct/' + $scope.pid,
        params: {
            format: 'jsonp',
            json_callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }
     }).then(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
     });
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the solution? Because i have tried console.log func also